# No module named django error when running any manage.py command in docker with docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm getting `ImportError: No module named django` when trying to up my containers running `docker-compose up`.

Here's my scenario:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - db:db
```

manage.py

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

- The containers were built successfully
- My packages are present in the container (I get them when I run `pip freeze`)

I've changed the manage.py content for

```
import django
print django.get_version()
```

and it worked.

This is basically the same example as in this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/), except for starting a new project.

Comment: 1. do you have the pythonpath set corretly?
2.Try not to use django.core.management.execute_from_command_line, but instead configurations.management.execute_from_command_line.

Comment: I didn't set anything about python as I execute manually and it works. using configurations.management didn't work either, same error.

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to simply call

```
python3.6 manage.py ...
```

instead of

```
python manage.py ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to ensure that the module was imported along with app name:

```py
from uploadapi.importers import Status
```

instead of

```py
from importers upload Status
```